# Best lifecycle component to use when using react-native with redux

Tags: react-native, redux, application-lifecycle

I'm trying to update a component after receiving props from redux using componentWillReceiveProps. On the next instance that props are sent to the component by redux componentWillReceiveProps does not fire a second time. Any idea why this is happening and the best lifecycle component to use in such a situation?.

Comment: You'll have to show us your code to get any kind of meaningful answer.

Comment: make sure your component is `connect`-ed with react-redux. That way you dont have to update manually. The component will re-render when prop changes.